# Check if sampler2D is empty

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm designing a sprite class, and I would like to display only a color if no texture is loaded.

Here are my vertex shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex; // <vec2 pos, vec2 tex>

out vec2 vs_tex_coords;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    vs_tex_coords = vertex.zw;
    gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

And the fragment shader :

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 vs_tex_coords;

out vec4 fs_color;

uniform sampler2D image;
uniform vec3 sprite_color;

void main()
{
    fs_color = vec4(sprite_color, 1.0) * texture(image, vs_tex_coords);
}
```

My problem is that if I don't bind a texture, it displays only a black sprite. I think the problem is that the texture function in my fragment shader returns a 0, and screw all the formula.

Is there a way to know if the sampler2D is not initialized or null, and just return the sprite_color?

Comment: Bind a 1x1 texture with the color you want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A sampler cannot be "empty". A valid texture *must* be bound to the texture units referenced by each sampler in order for rendering to have well-defined behavior.

But that doesn't mean you have to *read* from the texture that's bound there. It's perfectly valid to use a `uniform` value to tell the shader whether to read from the texture or not.

But you still have to bind a simple, 1x1 texture there. Indeed, you can use `textureSize` on the sampler; if it is a 1x1 texture, then don't bother to read from it. Note that this might be slower than using a `uniform`.

Comment: I use [this](https://hastebin.com/jivojakusi.hs) to generate an empty texture, but I still got a black output.

Comment: You supply too less data. A 1x1 RGBA texture needs at least 4 bytes.

Comment: Oh right silly me. I had to dig more to find a solution, but you both definitely helped me. I'll update the first post with my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here below the 2 versions, with and without `if... else...`  conditional statement. The conditional statement avoids to have to sample the texture if not used.

The `uniform int textureSample` is set to 1 or 0 for the texture or the color to show up respectively. Both uniform variables are normally set up by the program, not the shader.

```
uniform int textureSample = 1;
uniform vec3 color = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);


void main() {     // without if... else...

    // ...
    vec3 materialDiffuseColor = textureSample  * texture( textureSampler, fragmentTexture ).rgb - (textureSample - 1) * color;
    // ...
}


void main() {      // with if... else...

    // ...

if (textureSample == 1) {     // 1 if texture, 0 if color

    vec3 materialDiffuseColor = textureSample  * texture( textureSampler, fragmentTexture ).rgb;
    vec3 materialAmbientColor = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) * materialDiffuseColor;
    vec3 materialSpecularColor = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);

    gl_Color = brightness *
        (materialAmbientColor +
        materialDiffuseColor * lightPowerColor * cosTheta / distanceLight2 +
        materialSpecularColor * lightPowerColor * pow(cosAlpha, 10000) / distanceLight2);
}
else {
    vec3 materialDiffuseColor = color;
    vec3 materialAmbientColor = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) * materialDiffuseColor;
    vec3 materialSpecularColor = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);

    gl_Color = brightness *
        (materialAmbientColor +
        materialDiffuseColor * lightPowerColor * cosTheta / distanceLight2 +
        materialSpecularColor * lightPowerColor * pow(cosAlpha, 10000) / distanceLight2);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd check length of rgb for diffuse texture. This won't work on a specular map though

```
    vec3 texDiffuseCol = texture2D(diffuseTex, TexCoord).rgb;
    if(length(texDiffuseCol) == 0.0)
    {
        //Texture not present
    }else
    {
        //Texture present
    }
```

Comment: this is wrong. if no texture provided, there will a default fallback on rgb which is all (0, 0, 0), this doesn't solve ops question.

Comment: There are textures with black areas, this code will not work properly.

Comment: Yes. Won't work with specular texture